# Multiple email refer to single email

Tags: email, gmail, registration, sendgrid

In my development environment I need to create large amount of users. But there are limited emails owned by me.

If I enter invalid emails I can't confirm the email / or check confirmation email feature.

Is there any way to enter multiple emails that refer a single email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append plus(+) sign before at sign(@) in an email. Email clients ignore plus sign.

myaccount+2@test.com, myaccount+4@test.com send to **myaccount@test.com**

Helpful during development, signup your account with multiple different emails using plus (+) sign and you will get email in your single account.

cheers